# How to prevent Eclipse creates nmake file instead of make?

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt

In order to  develop  qt application on eclipse, i have installed mingw, qt and qt eclipse integration. When i try to build  the project, it search nmake  for  building  project and syntax of my make file is  nmake syntax.

And i thought  there were some special  eclipse settings but i could'nt find  anything about it.

How  can i  make eclipse  produce make file instead of nmake

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is  because of Qt version. Nmake is special for Visual Studio integrated Qt. So If your eclipse create nmake file instead of make file. Your eclipse show wrong version of Qt.

If you don't want to  get this error. You should firstly check:

1. Check you download true eclipse version. The Qt version which
2. eclipse is using is correct
3. Check QT_DIR in your enviroment variable  show  correct path.